ORA-00001: unique constraint (APEX_230200.WWV_DICTIONARY_CACHE_OBJ_IDX2) violated
I'm trying to create a page in Oracle Apex.
It's a form page. It's errored out with following message.
"ORA-00001: unique constraint (APEX_230200.WWV_DICTIONARY_CACHE_OBJ_IDX2) violated"
Refer to the screenshot attached.

There is no screenshot attached.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Looks like you'd have to refresh data dictionary cache. Here's how:

navigate to "Administration" (upper right corner, left of your username):
click "Manage Service"
in lower right corner, you'll see "Manage Meta Data" - click on "Data Dictionary cache"
finally, "Refresh Cache only"


